# How to set the Caret on the position of RightClick?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox with a SpellCheck implemented. I want to place the cursor/caret exactly where the rightclick is positioned. For example, if i have two misspelled words such as :

I ***belive*** this is ***wroking***

and I right click on "belive", the context menu that opens is based on Wroking, because my cursor was last positioned there. To open the list of suggested words of "belive", I have to first Left click on the word, to position the caret and then RightClick.

So to make it clear, I want to automatically position the caret where my cursor is on RightClick. Is it possible to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code you currently have to capture the mouse position and show the context menu? The default right click moves the caret and displays the context menu where you right click so it sounds like you've overridden this.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a way to solve the problem, by getting the mouseposition on ***MouseRightButtonUp* event** and attributing it to a TextPointer. From there, I can select the exact Range of the current word, and then do something with it.

`Point mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(textBox);`

`TextPointer current = textBox.GetPositionFromPoint(mousePoint, true);`